# If Text equals x, then transfer column y to column x

Tags: excel, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a drop-down list in column 3, and gross, gst and net amounts in column 4, 5 and 6.  I want set a formula so that if a specific name from the drop down list is selected that the net amount in column 6 will be transferred to another column specific to the name selected in the drop down list

E.g. Marketing is selected from drop down list in Column 3 - the net amount is $200.00 in column 6 - I want $200.00 to appear in the Column 15 which is the designated Marketing column.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
O1:    =IF(C1="Marketing",F1,"")
```